# Capture output written directly to Windows console

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core

I'm trying to capture the output of a Windows executable that's executed from C#. Currently, this is what I have:

```
private static string Execute(string pathToExe, string pathToInputFile, string pathToOutputFolder)
{
    var standardOutput = new StringBuilder();
    var errorOutput = new StringBuilder();

    var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = pathToExe;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{pathToInputFile}\" \"{pathToOutputFolder}\"";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) => standardOutput.AppendLine(eventArgs.Data);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) => errorOutput.AppendLine(eventArgs.Data);

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit(-1);

    return standardOutput.ToString() + errorOutput.ToString();
}
```

Instead of returning the console output of the executable, I'm only getting a blank string. Instead, the output is being written to my application's console.

I believe this is because the executable I'm running actually launches a GUI program. When run from the command line, the app exposes a CLI. It's my guess that the application is attaching itself to the current console instead of attaching to a new one that's monitored by my application.

For example, running the following in PowerShell 7 results in the output still being written to the console, as opposed to being redirected to the output.txt file:

```
external.exe --help *> output.txt
```

So it seems the executable isn't writing to one of the standard output streams.

Does anyone have any ideas or workarounds that would work in .NET Core 3.1 on Windows?

Comment: Have you tried setting StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true?

Comment: @jscarle Adding that option results in the output no longer being written to my app's console, but it still doesn't capture the output.

Comment: I have a feeling that the executable you are launching isn't using stdout. Have you tried running it through cmd.exe? Or testing a different executable?

Comment: Do you mean executing cmd.exe in my app, passing in the executable as an argument? Or do you literally just mean opening a Command Prompt and running the executable?

Comment: Executing cmd.exe with your executable as an argument.

Comment: Running `cmd.exe external.exe` in PowerShell does not result in output to the console. I've added a note about the fact that the executable isn't writing to one of the available output streams. I believe it's writing directly to the console.